# Filling in a data table where an SQL query only returns a single result

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I've got an application on which the user will, one barcode at a time, scan a barcode into a text field. That barcode is then validated against an existing database using a query. This query will return a single row from the database which is then added to a second data table to populate a DataGridView.

Note - the barcode scanner send CR/LF after the code, so there's no button to 'submit' that barcode for query.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Eq9.jpg (kept getting errors trying to upload the image here)

The operator will do this until they have scanned all the barcodes they need to, at which point there should be a row in the DataGridView for each of these barcodes.

At present, I am filling in the DataGridView at the end of the same function that grabs the data from the SQL server - Code snippet:

```
Public Function GetResults() As DataTable

        Dim dtResults As New DataTable
        Dim dtScanned As New DataTable
        Dim connString As String = "Data Source=SQL03\SQL2019;Initial Catalog=aa"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("
                SELECT requests.request_id AS 'Request ID', patients.first_name AS GivenName, patients.surname AS Surname,
                concat(patients.day_birth, '/', patients.month_birth, '/', patients.year_birth) AS DOB, patients.sex AS 'Sex',
                services.service_abbrev AS 'Ref.Service', specimens.specimen AS 'Specimen', referral_details.referral_dt AS 'Referral Date'
                
                FROM
                { insert a bunch of joins here }

                WHERE
                    referral_details.referral_dt >= @StartDate AND
                    referral_details.referral_dt <= @EndDate AND
                    labs.lab_id = '46' AND
                    requests.request_id = @LabID
                
                ORDER BY
                    labs.lab_name ASC,
                    requests.request_id ASC,
                    services.service_abbrev ASC

                ", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTo.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LabID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtBarcode.Text
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dtResults.Load(reader)



Process:
                    If dtResults.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("No referral found for this Lab ID.", "No Referral", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Else
                        Return dtResults
                    End If

                Catch Ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to SQL Server. Please check your network connection and if required, report the issue to IT." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Ex.Message, "No Connection!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End Using

        End Using

        For Each dr As DataRow In dtResults.Rows
            dtScanned.ImportRow(dr)

        Next

        Return dtScanned

    End Function
```

My issue is that every time a barcode is scanned, the first row in the DataGridView is replaced by the new data. Now, I feel this makes sense in that I am 'recreating' the data table each time a scan is entered, but I'm not sure how/where to store the data from each scan that will have it show up in the DataGridView as it is scanned. From my limited understanding, an array or additional data table isn't going to help because I'll have the same limitations.

How can I have each scan appear as a new row in the DataGridView as it is scanned given we are only pulling one record from the SQL server at a time? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Load method has options. You can specify that you want to "PreserveChanges" as a second parameters in the load method. See the link below.  Another approach is to use the data from the reader and manually use the DataTable rows add method. As a side remark, It looks like you have extra Conn.Open after Try. See this link for options on load:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-6.0

Comment: [DataTable.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge), so you can control how the new data is added to the existing DataTable. Or `Load()` the new data directly into the existing DataTable, depending on the use-case -- Read the Remarks section of both methods with care

Comment: You also have the [LoadDataRow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow) method (to use on the existing DataTable - Remarks section of it still quite important)